# lightning out not working with login flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-out, loginflow

I've a login flow which uses flow and lightning component to present few screens. Issue with flow screens is these screens are not wide enough. I tried to use login flow with VF to get better control on UI. I'm creating lightning:flow component in lightning out script but its not working. When I preview the same VF from dev console, it works fine.
VF with lightning out is used to get lightning runtime experience for flow. Otherwise, it can render flow but in old classic experience.
VF Page:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <apex:includeLightning />

  </head>
  <body class="slds-scope">
      Text Message
     <div id="flowContainer" />
     <script>
        var statusChange = function (event) {
           if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
              // Control what happens when the interview finishes

              var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
              var key;
              for(key in outputVariables) {
                 if(outputVariables[key].name === "myOutput") {
                    // Do something with an output variable
                 }
              }
           }
        };
        console.log('right before calling use function');
        $Lightning.use("c:lightningOutApp", function() {
           console.log('in the callback of use function');
           // Create the flow component and set the onstatuschange attribute
           $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {"onstatuschange":statusChange},
              "flowContainer",
              function (component) {

                 // Start an interview in the flowContainer div, and 
                 // initializes the input variables.
                 component.startFlow("User_Provisioning_Flow");
              }
           );
        });
     </script>
  </body>
```

Lightning App:

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp">
   <aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow"/> 
</aura:application>
```

Error coming in console:

[image]

I'm not able to understand the error but this is causing the issue. I don't get this error if page previewed from developer console. My assumption is that due to restricted session in login flow, this is happening. If this is right then is there any way to increase the width of login flow screens which are rendered by flow screen components.

Comment: Ashish, did you work this one out?

Comment: @TheCloudFox, Yes, I was able to increase width of login flow screen with Lazy-Loading CSS.

Comment: Ah OK - do you mean loading CSS from a hidden Aura / LWC component that is positioned within the Flow screen?

Comment: It was LWC we were already using to show form upon user login. Create a CSS file with style classes used by flow container. I dont remeber the exact css class name but it was a container class. Loading CSS in a static resource allows us to change CSS of components which aren't owned by our custom component as explained here which we cannot do otherwise as explained here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css

Comment: Use of lightning out component is not supported in VF Login Flow