# Using lightning:inputField, I want to remove helptext

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield, helptext

I'm using lightning:input-field in LWC, but I want only the input field, nothing else.
I have hide the label using variant="label-hidden", but I automatically get the help-text near the field.
And I don't want it in my component.

[image]

My code is :

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the markup to verify that the help text is part of the `lightning-input-field` and not part of another element?

Comment: Yup I checked and help text is part of `lightning-input-field` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 2 solutions to this.

LWC is enforcing the shadow DOM style scoping, so you can't currently style other Elements outside your shadow tree.

Workaround 1 :-  As a workaround we can use the aura component to override the styling of LWC inner elements ( Aura components do not enforce strict CSS encapsulation so the CSS will come in action here). Inspect the particular help icon area on page and find some unique class of help icon. And add below styling to your aura component CSS file (Note: This will NOT work in LWC CSS file as LWC enforce strict CSS encapsulation.) and then implement your LWC in that Aura component.

```
   .THIS .slds-form-element__icon {/* Replace this class name "slds-form-element__icon" by your finding. */
    display: none !important;
}
```

Implement LWC (named as testDOM) in Aura :-

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride">
    <c:testDOM/>
</aura:component>
```

Workaround 2 :- We have one more workaround to this where we don't use Aura Component but put the CSS that we wanted to apply to the inner shadow DOM of Salesforce Base Components in a static resource. Then we used the loadStyle method of lightning/platformResourceLoader module to load that css. The styles loaded this way do apply to the inner elements within Salesforce base components.

Answer (score 4):

> Remove the help text from the field definition.

[image]

Comment: But that do not solve my purpose as ultimately I need a custom label for that standard field and I am using below code :-

`<label class="slds-form-element__label" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;">Account Name</label>
                                    <lightning-helptext class="customIcon" content={fieldsInfo.AccountId.inlineHelpText}></lightning-helptext>
                                    <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>`

and helptext will display nothing for lightning-helptext

Comment: Try using <lightning-input type="text" name="textInput" label="Enter a Text" ></lightning-input>

Comment: Here I have a lookup field and as per the documentation lightning-input dont have any type=lookup.

Answer (score 3):

My LWC Solution:

On your record edit form's onload, pass a method with below JS code included.

HTML:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form onload={handleLoad}>
      <lightning-input-field lwc-dom="manual" class="hideHelpText" field-name="my_field" variant="label-hidden"> </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS:

```
handleLoad()
{
    try 
    {
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerText = `c-my-class .slds-button__icon {
        display: none;
        }`;
        this.template.querySelector('.hideHelpText').appendChild(style);

    } catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    }

    this.myHideString = 'slds-show';
}
```

If you are displaying the record-edit-form in a modal like I am, and you are using a loading symbol or hiding your fields: make sure you hide your 'loading' fields by wrapping them in a div with the class="slds-hide" and "slds-show". This allows the form fields to load while being hidden so that template's query selector can grab them.

Notes:

- 'my-class' is the name the class called 'myClass'. Must be preceded by c- in my case.
- might not need [lwc-dom="manual"]

Two helpful documents:

https://www.vernica.net/2019/07/lwc-override-css-of-standard-lightning-components.html

[Target inner elements of standard Lightning Web Components with CSS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a style sheet as a static resource (needed for scoping issues; regular CSS sheet won't work), import it in your component, and attach a class to the div or whatever is wrapping your lightning-input-field. The class in the stylesheet needs to drill down in the component structure and manually hide the tooltip. I've have to do this for a few components. Since lightning web components aren't open source, you'll need to look the structure with *inspector*. Of course, realize that if salesforce changes the structure of the component in the future, your CSS override could stop working.