# How to remove help text of lightning-input-field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

I have inserted LWC on VF page using lightning out. In my LWC, I have used `lightning-input-field`. The help text on the label is not displaying properly. I am guessing that it's because of lightning out. Hence I removed the label using `variant="label-hidden"` but the help text of the label still exists. Is there a way to remove it? I did not find anything helpful in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation).

[image]

CODE:

```js
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName}>
     <lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={item.value.inputFieldName} value={item.value.filterValue}>
     </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Comment: Is there `<lightning-helptext></lightning-helptext>` tags somewhere in the component?

Comment: @Zach No, I am using a standard `lightning-input-field` and I have not added any other tag to the component. If I remove `variant="label-hidden"`, I get the label and the help text for the field. If  I add `variant="label-hidden"`, I get just the help text. I wish to remove the help text because it's not displaying properly in lightning out.

Comment: @Zach I have raised an idea regarding the issue. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000015F7xQAE

Comment: My answer on this post might help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274562/using-lightninginputfield-i-want-to-remove-helptext/361767#361767

Comment: My answer on this post might help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274562/using-lightninginputfield-i-want-to-remove-helptext/361767#361767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the particular object's field ("myCustomField__c") in in your Org and remove the HelpText value given there. It go out from the Lightning page.

2. Or you inspect the particular help icon area on page and find the some unique class of help icon.And just override the class with  display: none;  .
   You can refer this [https://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2019/07/lwc-override-css-of-standard-lightning-components.html] to override the css in Lwc.

Answer (score 0):

my answer on this post should help if you are looking for a solution in LWC

[Using lightning:inputField, I want to remove helptext](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274562/using-lightninginputfield-i-want-to-remove-helptext/361767#361767)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).