# How to change CSS of a lightning-accordion-section label in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I can't change the CSS of the accordion title because of the shadow DOM in lwc. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Here is the code:

```html
<lightning-accordion onsectiontoggle={handleToggleSection} active-section-name={itemConfig} allow-multiple-sections-open >
    <lightning-accordion-section name="MyForm" label="MyForm" class="accordionPadding_small"></lightning-accordion-section>
</lightning-accordion>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible directly. You can check [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css/247392)

**Requote**

> LWC is enforcing the [shadow DOM
>   style](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#styling)
>   scoping, so you can't currently style other Elements outside your
>   shadow tree.
>
> That being said, there is the on-going [`::part` and
>   `::theme`](https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/) proposal
>   that would allow components to safely expose some of their internals
>   outside their shadow tree to be customized. This feature [will be
>   shipped in future releases](https://twitter.com/shadow_hayato/status/1086099822933815297) and
>   the rest of the browser vendors are supportive. We are currently
>   evaluating how to add this in LWC and in the lightning base
>   components.

Also note that although officially undocumented, you can change the CSS through static resource CSS file and by using [loadStyle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library) - this can reach inside LWC shadow DOM. There is no guarantee that this will work in future releases.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try this