# How to make buttons in a lightning-datatable smaller in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable, lightning-button, shadow-dom

I have a `lightning-datatable` in my Lightning Web Component (LWC) that has several buttons in each row (first button only shown here):

[image: Table snippet]

These standard-sized buttons consume quite a lot of vertical space so I thought CSS like this in my component would help:

```
button.slds-button {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
```

i.e. scale down all buttons inside my component.

But it does not, I assume because of the "parent can’t reach into a child" described in [Create a CSS Style Sheet for a Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_css). That is, my component cannot reach inside the `lightning-datatable` to reach the buttons.

Passing a CSS class in the columns data of the `lightning-datatable` for the buttons does work, at least when using an SLDS class like `slds-hidden`; the [lightning-button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/documentation) documentation says that:

> You can also apply utility classes with the class attribute.

and the class name is set in the DOM and works for classes like `slds-hidden`. But I haven't managed to scale the buttons using this approach. Perhaps this is another level of "parent can’t reach into a child": this time it is that `lightning-datatable` can't reach inside `lightning-button`.

A clear explanation of what is going on (or links to such an explanation) would be appreciated. And is there any way to scale down the buttons for this case?

**PS**

The current .css file in my component contains:

```
.scaled-down {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
```

and my component contains:

```
        <lightning-datatable
                class="slds-table_striped"
                key-field="Id"
                data={claims}
                columns={columns}
                hide-checkbox-column
                >
        </lightning-datatable>
```

and an example button column definition is:

```
const columns = [
    {
        type: "button",
        fixedWidth: 150,
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'View Details',
            title: 'View Details',
            name: 'viewDetails',
            value: 'viewDetails',
            variant: 'brand',
            class: 'scaled-down'
        }
    },
```

And the output using "Inspect" in Chrome is:

```
<lightning-button class="scaled-down">
    <button name="viewDetails" title="View Details" type="button"
        class="slds-button slds-button_brand">View Details</button>
</lightning-button>
```

**PPS**

Some progress. Manually editing in Chrome this doesn't scale the button:

```
<lightning-button style="transform: scale(0.75)">
    <button name="viewDetails" title="View Details" type="button"
        class="slds-button slds-button_brand">View Details</button>
</lightning-button>
```

but this does scale the button:

```
<lightning-button>
    <button style="transform: scale(0.75)"
        name="viewDetails" title="View Details" type="button"
        class="slds-button slds-button_brand">View Details</button>
</lightning-button>
```

Unfortunately this CSS selector **doesn't** work:

```
.scaled-down button {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the standard `slds-*` CSS classes, if you created a custom CSS class (i.e. `makeSmaller`) and set the properties of that class and then apply the class to your button, can you see if that works?

Comment: I’ll check. Offline for an hour though.

Comment: did you try `initialWidth` property ?

Comment: @BryanAnderson Passing an explicit class name does not work with either of the CSS definition `.abcdef` or `.abcdef button`.

Comment: @sdandamud1 I am already using `initialWidth` and when I set that to a small value the button text wraps i.e. the buttons are not scaled as I would like.

Comment: @KeithC would you mind including the CSS / styles file for your lightning component

Comment: Hi @BryanAnderson, I've added the relevant bits. Thanks.

Comment: @KeithC I think you need to add the `.THIS` to your CSS file, from the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm

Comment: @BryanAnderson Note this is LWC not Aura. I've made that clearer in the question.

Comment: @Keith , as per doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation. there is no `class` type attribute for button type action.

Comment: @sdandamud1 Yeah. However, the value is passed through - see my PS.

Comment: @KeithC this answer suggests wrapping aura around LWC allows you to target inner elements , might worth a try? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal, See the answer I just added - I better understand what is going on now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.5 years later there seems to be a cleaner way if you're OK with using a beta feature.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/

You need to go to LDS page for the component you're interested in and scroll all the way down, for example https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#Styling-Hooks-Overview

I needed custom button colo(u)r and making them nice and round. Simply add this to the CSS file

```
:host {
    --sds-c-button-brand-color-background: #006CF4;
    --sds-c-button-brand-color-background-hover: #003578;
    --sds-c-button-radius-border: 20px;
}
```

[image: buttons with rounded borders]

No `cellAttributes`, no hacks with special class added at runtime. My datatable's column is just

```
{
    label: 'Click to retrieve', type: 'button', fieldName: 'quoteRetrievalURL', typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'quoteRetrievalRef' },
        variant: 'brand'
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Great solution !!

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Wei Ni's answer (do upvote that), I think I now better understand what is going on.

I have been adding this CSS to my component:

```
.scaled-down button {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
```

which outputs this into the resulting HTML page:

```
<style type="text/css">
.scaled-down[cvnp-claims_claims] button[cvnp-claims_claims] {
    transform:scale(.75)
}
</style>
```

meaning this style [only applies to elements that have an attribute](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-attribute-selector/) named `cvnp-claims_claims`. That attribute name is added by LWC to many elements output directly by my component e.g.:

```
<lightning-card cvnp-claims_claims>
    ...
    <lightning-datatable cvnp-claims_claims>
        ...
```

but in this case, not the buttons (or any other cell content) that is output by the `lightning-datatable`:

```
<lightning-button class="scaled-down">
    <button name="viewDetails" title="View Details" type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand">View Details</button>
</lightning-button>
```

I presume this is by design, but it is not helpful for my case...

The cleanest way to go, I think, is to pass in the style in the column definition:

```
{
    type: "button",
    fixedWidth: 150,
    typeAttributes: {
        label: 'View Details',
        title: 'View Details',
        name: 'viewDetails',
        value: 'viewDetails',
        variant: 'brand'
    },
    cellAttributes: {
        style: 'transform: scale(0.75)'
    }
}
```

so it is output like this:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="transform: scale(0.75);">
```

which works. Inserting some CSS that is not qualified by the attribute somehow would be another approach. But note that you get this error if you attempt to add `style` directly in the template:

> The  element is disallowed inside the template. Please add css
>   rules into '.css' file of your component bundle.

Incidentally, while I'm now getting the styling applied, it is not quite right yet as the buttons are scaled-down but the row height is unchanged... But that is a CSS challenge - unsolved at present - not a LWC problem.

**PS**

See [How to escape lightning CSS scoping](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286220/how-to-escape-lightning-css-scoping) for adding CSS not qualified an attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it myself, but if this can get background color working, it should work for the size as well.

https://sfdcfacts.com/lwc/color-columns-of-data-table-lwc/

[image]

Basically, what it does is adding class attribute as part of cell attributes then manually assign class to it when define data.

```
{label: ‘Diet Type’, fieldName: ‘diet’, type: ‘text’, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: ‘dietCSSClass’ }}},
{diet : ‘Vegeterian’, dietCSSClass : ‘diet-veg’}
```

This will create a row in the data table with cell value as “Vegeterian”. Also you can have the definition of the class “diet-veg” in the CSS file of your component which will be applied to this cell.

```
.diet-veg{
background : yellowgreen;
}
```

Just did sth myself out of curiosity, in case the class cell attribute is not working, I replace it with Style and in the data column, I directly specify the style I want to, seems working as expected.

Example:

```
{label: 'Working', fieldName: 'working', type: 'boolean', cellAttributes: { style: { fieldName: 'workingCSSClass' }}}

data.push({working : true, workingCSSClass : 'background:black'});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Making some progress with `cellAttributes: { style: 'transform: scale(0.75); }`; setting the `style` seems to be a help or me. Haven't figured out what I am doing that is different to what you are doing yet.