# How to escape lightning CSS scoping

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I have a component called `basic`, with the following in it's css file (basic.css)

```
td {
 background: red;
}
```

The rendered CSS comes out like

```
td[c-basic_basic]{background: red;}
```

Is there a way to make the rendered CSS come out like

```
td{background: red;}
```

from within that basic.css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the only way to get literal CSS loaded is to use [loadStyle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation). CSS is not meant to be "broken out of", because that is the design of LWC. You can read more about the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom) for more information.