# Alternative method for aura:html (<aura:html tag="style">) in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, alternatives

How can I access the top level CSS in LWC? In Aura component I use

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container { 
        width : 60% !important; max-width : 80% !important; 
    } 
</aura:html>
```

what is the alternative method in Lightning Web Component?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by "top level CSS" here. AFAIK you cannot modify the SLDS CSS that other components are using; you can only modify the SLDS CSS for your component.

LWC automatically scopes the CSS you include in your component to apply to that component only via your component's name added as an attribute. See the answer on [How to make buttons in a lightning-datatable smaller in LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285718/how-to-make-buttons-in-a-lightning-datatable-smaller-in-lwc) for a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this in .css file of the Lightning Web Component.
In Salesforce, you don't get the `.css` file by default, you need to create it from VS Code. Just create a file in your components folder name it like `componentName.css`, now add your CSS code in that.

See the [playground Demo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/rC2RdWGp/1/edit).

Comment: I am asking about adding style to the corresponding component. Please refer the <aura:html> tag in aura component. I just want an alternative for that in LWC. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielDeepak are you looking for a dynamic component or unescaped HTML in Lwc?

Comment: Unescaped HTML exactly, Rahul. Thanks in advance.