# LWC lightning-accordion-section title or header background

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like to add background to the lightning-accordion-section header alone. I tried by using background color. It is showing the background color even when it is expanded.

Similar Question - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pntJQAQ

Comment: Can you make a [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) to demonstrate exactly what you've done?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/aFcv00-QJ/11/edit. It is not showing the background. But, it is showing in my dev org.

Comment: @MagulanDuraipandian Which background? the accordion header or body or something else?

Comment: Just the header background. But, it is applying the background to whole section.

Comment: @MagulanDuraipandian so are you trying to apply different background colors to the header and section?

Comment: I am looking for adding color only to the header. Check the Similar question link in the question. The standard page layout sections have this.

Comment: Idea Post - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015DFrQAM

Comment: Actually you need to override the standard Lightning web component css using the static resource css. or there is other way in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css) See the answer by  Benjamin Vogler

Answer (score 4):

There are styling hooks for standard lwc components. For your particular scenario, use "--sds-c-accordion-summary-color-background". In the css file, add this to the accordion and specify the color you want.

For more info, refer https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/

Comment: For anyone looking for the complete solution to use the hooks, here's what you need to put in your CSS file:


    :host {
        --sds-c-accordion-summary-color-background: var(--lwc-colorBackground,rgb(243, 242, 242));
    }

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following steps:

1. Create a css file on your system.
2. Add the following into the css file:

```
.slds-accordion__summary-content{
//Your CSS fixes here
}
```

3. Place this file in a .zip folder.
4. Upload this file onto a static resource.
5. In your LWC, add the following lines on the top:

```
import <import_name> from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/<static_resource_name>";
import { loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
```

6. Add this method to the .js file of your LWC component:

```
renderedCallback() 
{
    Promise.all([loadStyle(this, <import_name> + "/<css_file_name>.css")])
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Static Resource Loaded");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error-", error);
        });
}
```