# lightning edit page of custom object element resize

Tags: lightning

Is there a way which I could edit or add new components to the lightning edit page?

for example:

I have a custom Object.

when I click on the Edit page (lightning env) I have a rich-text field with other standard and custom fields.

The rich-text height is very small, and a long text will do the following:

[image]

I want to add some css to this standard component like : `max-height:100%` But I don't sure where to do it and if it possible at all.

And all these text will be shown without the option to scroll down.

for example (After inspecting and add the style to this field):

[image]

Or create a Component a component of rich text and add it to the Edit page - didn't find a way to do so.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply styles to standard components. You can apply styles to custom components that you create. I tried to create a custom component to solve your question using the standard [lightning-input-rich-text component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text) but it happens that the inner elements of that component [cannot be styled because of shadow DOM](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css).

In conclusion, there's no easy way to do it. You'll have to build something completely custom.