# LWC typo in documentation

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a typo in these [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getters_setters)? Shouldn't the template reference `{itemName}` instead of `{uppercaseItemName}`? Is there maybe some smart mapping that knows if the getter returns that specific variable so we can name property functions whatever we want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either will work, though I get where you're coming from and agree it would make more sense to use `itemName`.

We handle this with a naming convention; if we deem a property to be "private", we start the property name with an underscore and we should see no reference to such a name from the template or elsewhere outside the component's JS file. We also use JSDoc to mark it private.

So for us this example would look like:

template:

```
<template>
    {itemName}
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class TodoItem extends LightningElement {
    /**
     * The upper case version of the specified itemName.
     *
     * @type {string|undefined}
     * @private
     */
    _uppercaseItemName;

    @api
    get itemName() {
        return this._uppercaseItemName;
    }

    set itemName(value) {
       this._uppercaseItemName = value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps one of the developers of LWC? If so, can you take a look at this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334634/lwc-setting-properties-in-connectedcallback

Comment: Hi @MichaelMunta no, I work for an ISV developing on the platform. I'll have a look when I find the time and will comment or answer if I can.

Comment: As an additional question isn't the method of using `{uppercaseItemName}` in the template slower? In the sense of the compiler needing to search through functions to find references to the field in question while in the case of `{itemName}` it immediately knows which function to call?

Comment: It's just getting a property from the underlying JavaScript object that represents the component. In one case it is a plain property, in the other it's one with a getter function. There shouldn't be any real difference in performance in this case, and what difference there is would be under the hood, in the JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Just tested this and the thing is that the getter isn't actually called when you reference `{uppercaseItemName}`. It gets called only when we reference `{itemName}` and that was my question. I assumed that the docs wanted to show that if we reference a field inside a template then the compiler would know to call the appropriate getter by matching the references, but that isn't the case.

Comment: The property getter is only for `itemName` so naturally is only invoked when that property is referenced. The fact that the property getter/setter pair use a "private" property is an internal detail. Direct access to that "private" property will always only involve that property or **its** getter/setter. It would not make any sense for the LWC compiler to generate JavaScript that behaved any other way.

Comment: Direct access to a property will only involve that property or its getter/setter? How can it involve its getter/setter if the property is called directly? In the case from the docs, if we reference `{uppercaseItemName}` we are directly involving only that property, NOT its getter/setter.

Comment: A JavaScript property is either defined by a simple property name or it is defined using getters and setters. What I meant was that you could equally define `uppercaseItemName` as having a getter and setter but that you must use the name of the property or its getter to access that property.